# How to identify the start and the end of a sequence inside a list in Python?

Tags: python, list

Imagine that you have completed experiments with using different sample materials in a sequence. You have completed your experiments, and you are satisfied with the results (it may take a few tries) before you start with a different sample material, so the sequences will appear after each other:

```
list_ex = ['Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Steel', 'Steel', 'Aluminium', 'Aluminium', 'Aluminium']
```

Another list is also introduced which is appropriately named `quality` in order to distinguish between good and bad measurements:

```
quality = ['BAD', 'BAD', 'BAD', 'GOOD', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'GOOD', 'BAD', 'GOOD', 'GOOD']
```

which is applied in a list comprehension to rule out the bad measurements using `True` and `False`:

```
qual = [True if _ == 'GOOD' else False if _ == 'BAD' else False for _ in quality]
```

From the example, you see that one sequence of materials follows the other with no intercrossing. However, I would like to categorize the data by finding the start and the end of each sequence in order to do something like this:

```
list_iron  = list_ex[start_iron:end_iron+1]
list_steel = list_ex[start_steel:end_steel+1]
list_alu   = list_ex[start_alu:end_alu+1]
```

which would yield the following outputs:

```
In[1]:  list_iron
Out[1]: ['Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron']

In[2]:  list_steel
Out[2]: ['Steel', 'Steel']

In[3]:  list_alu
Out[3]: ['Aluminium', 'Aluminium', 'Aluminium']
```

The reason why I would like to find the start and the end is that I would like to use these to identify the position of other data that are based on these (thank you, Matt B. for pointing out that my true intentions were poorly formulated):

```
In[4]:  freq_steel = frequency[start_steel:end_steel+1]
In[5]:  freq_steel
Out[5]: [[100, 200, 300, 400, 500], [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]]
```

But since one of the steel measurements were bad, I would ideally want to:

```
In[6]:  qual_steel = quality[start_steel:end_steel+1]
In[7]:  qual_steel
Out[7]: [False, True]
In[8]:  freq_steel[qual_steel]
Out[8]: [1000, 2000, 3000, 4000, 5000]
```

- Is there an elegant way of doing this in Python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out two ways that works, but it may not be the best ways of doing it, as I consider myself very much a novice. Firstly, alternative A:

```
def finder(lst, condition):
    return [a for a, b in enumerate(lst) if condition(b)]

iron  = finder(Material, lambda _: _ == 'Iron')
steel = finder(Material, lambda _: _ == 'Steel')
alu   = finder(Material, lambda _: _ == 'Aluminium')

start_iron  = iron[0]
end_iron    = iron[-1]
start_steel = steel[0]
end_steel   = steel[-1]
start_alu   = alu[0]
end_alu     = alu[-1]
```

Secondly, alternative B:

```
iron  = [_ for _ in Material if _ == 'Iron']
steel = [_ for _ in Material if _ == 'Steel']
alu   = [_ for _ in Material if _ == 'Aluminium']

n_iron  = len(iron)
n_steel = len(steel)
n_alu   = len(alu)

start_iron  = 0
end_iron    = n_iron
start_steel = end_iron
end_steel   = start_steel + n_steel
start_alu   = end_steel
end_alu     = start_alu + n_alu
```

This can then, in turn, be used to do the rest I described in the original question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use list comprehension to do just this;

```
list_iron = [item for item in list_ex if item == 'Iron']
list_steel = [item for item in list_ex if item == 'Steel']
```

So on, so forth..

And you can then adapt the comprehension to build lists from different criteria.

Comment: Thank you, @Matt B. This is what I initially did, but since I need to use these intervals for the rest of my datasets (it is merely a way of distinguishing what to extract), I was hoping there was another way of doing it. I apologize for my poor description.

Comment: No problem! Then definitely take a look at @chepner 's solution, that way you can build the lists without knowing the contents. Probably best to use the dictionary solution so you can call a key to grab the full list!

Answer (score 1):

Try `itertools.groupby`:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> [list(v) for _, v in itertools.groupby(list_ex)]
[['Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron'], ['Steel', 'Steel'], ['Aluminium', 'Aluminium', 'Aluminium']]
>>> {k: list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(list_ex)}
{'Iron': ['Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron', 'Iron'], 'Steel': ['Steel', 'Steel'], 'Aluminium': ['Aluminium', 'Aluminium', 'Aluminium']}
```